# Why introduced for loop when we have itreator With Using Same Map Entry Function

Tags: java

When We have for lop then why we have use iterator following code are some working as Result give by iterator

```
public class HashMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> hasmap  = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hasmap.put("1", "Java");
        hasmap.put("2", ".Net");
        hasmap.put("3", "C++");
        hasmap.put("4", "Pearl");
        hasmap.put("5", "PHP");

        for (Entry<String, String> entry : hasmap.entrySet()) {

                System.out.println("For Loop Get Key"+entry.getKey());
                System.out.println("For Loop Get Value"+entry.getValue());

        }
        Set set = hasmap.entrySet();
        Iterator itr =  set.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry map = (Entry) itr.next();
            System.out.println(map.getKey());
            System.out.println(map.getValue());
        }


    }   

}
```

Comment: Accessing the underlying iterator permits you to safely remove elements from the map while iterating. This is not possible with the for-each loop, which is basically a read-only operation on your data-structure. So if your intent is to print the content, use the for-each loop. Less code to write and less error prone.

Comment: try to just  print "Hello World " 1000 times. or assign random value to a int array of 1000 lenght.

Comment: The iterator was there well before the enhanced for-each loop was introduced.in Java 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the iterative loop you have in your post is a matter of historical use; the [foreach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop#Java) loop was introduced in Java 1.5.

Until that point, foreach loops were achieved using the [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) construct (which has been available [since Java 1.2](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.2-docs/api/)).

---

One reason to use `Iterator` is for its `.remove()` method, which safely removes an element without throwing a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), which is thrown whenever a loop is modified while it is being iterated (which is not allowed in Java).

On the other hand, simple foreach loops in Java are read only, but are more succinct and generally result in cleaner, easier to read code:

```
for (String str : array) {
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

versus

```
Iterator<String> arrayItr = array.iterator();
while (arrayItr.hasNext()) {
  String str = arrayItr.next();
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, when we think about Iterator below are advantages of iterator and not available in for loop concept:

1. remove() option is available in Iterator.
2. Fail fast and Fail Safe iterator are available in Iterator concept.

Comment: How is fail fast not available in simple foreach?

Comment: Yes.. Fail fast is available in Foreach. :(

Comment: Fail fast is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

From this answer: [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

The `for-each` loop can only iterate over an object that is an array or in instance of `Iterable`. Thus the `iterator` of the object is used in the `for-each` loop, but you cannot call `i.remove()` because the iterator is merely inferred.

```
for(Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String item = i.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```